# ¿Por qué una función se iguala a 0?

Tags: c++, funciones, class, diseño-de-clases

¿Porque esta funcion se iguala a 0?
¿Que significa?

```
class visitor
{
  public:
    virtual void visit(element_concrete_1& el) = 0;
    virtual void visit(element_concrete_2& el) = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Esto significa que estas funciones son [virtuales puras](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class), y la clase es una clase abstracta.